# Xamarin.Android: Error android.view.View.mPrivateFlags NullReferenceException

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, nullreferenceexception

I have a xamarin.forms project using Xamarin.Forms 3.2.0.871581 (I know I should update but I am always worried that updates of Xamarin introduces new bugs..).

And sometimes I have the following unhandled exception which pops and crashes but I do not find any information on the internet and it is very difficult to trace and debug:

```
EXCEPTION: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mPrivateFlags' on a null object reference AT   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualBooleanMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00089] in <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0 
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0 
at Android.Views.View.DispatchTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x00031] in <95d915721ad748108ff096dce8f8f32c>:0 
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].DispatchTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x00012] in <b9bd728dc3884553a65889a49f5d7aad>:0 
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform+DefaultRenderer.DispatchTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x00007] in <b9bd728dc3884553a65889a49f5d7aad>:0 
at Android.Views.View.n_DispatchTouchEvent_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_e) [0x00011] in <95d915721ad748108ff096dce8f8f32c>:0 
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.24(intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

It seems that there is a problem with the dispatchTouchEvent but I am quit lost on how to debug and solve such error.
I can provide with the full stacktrace if anyone wants to.

Has anyone already faced this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You are only 3 years behind in updating Xamarin.Forms. Good luck on getting any help.

Comment: Yes, I know but I took the work of another development teams, and I am alone, I know I should try to update this big project, but alone is very difficult... Thanks anyway. But does nyone know at least what could raise this error?

Comment: The error message you provided is hard to tell where the problem is, any click or touch event will trigger dispatchTouchEvent.

Comment: I an provide the full stacktrace if you want to @Leo Zhu? And how can I detect where this error happen, should I add logs everywhere and pray that it happens in debug mode? Thanks you

Comment: @J.Doe In fact, your version is so old that it is likely to change during a version update that it is incompatible.You could show a full stacktrace,and i will check it,but could not necessarily find the issue.

Comment: @Leo Zhu: You will find below my answer containing the full stack trace if you have time to look at it. But what did you mean by: 'your version is so old that it is likely to change during a version update that it is incompatible'? Did you mean that the Xamarin.Forms version is too old that you will  not be able to detect why the pb is happening? Anyway, I appreciate your help and time. Thanks